# I configured javaagent for Kafka jmx_exporter and now I can't create topic or get the list of them. I get this error:

Tags: apache-kafka

In docker compose file, I added this configuration:

`KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: '-javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=7071:/opt/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml`

Also I tried this one:

`KAFKA_OPTS: '-javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=9999:/opt/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml'`

This is the error:

```
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
        at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
        at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:130)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer.<init>(HTTPServer.java:190)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:31)
        ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Aborted
```

**Also I checked the port that I exposed for jmx_exporter and it doesn't have any problem and confliction.**

Comment: What is the port that you exposed for jmx ? what is your kafka configuration, variable environment ?

Comment: `Address already in use` - Either something else is already using the port, or you are attempting to start a second instance.

Comment: @SaraM. I edited my question.

Comment: @FatemehHaeri see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found another way to config JMX agent. Instead of adding -javaagent config in KAFKA_OPTS, it has to be written in EXTRA_ARGS field, plus, JMX_PORT has to be commented or removed and instead of that the port has to be written in JMX_PROMETHEUS_PORT field.

This is the result:

```
EXTRA_ARGS: '-javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=7071:/opt/prometheus/kafka-2_0_0.yml'
#JMX_PORT: 7071
JMX_PROMETHEUS_PORT: 7071
KAFKA_OPTS: '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost'
```

These configurations are working for me really well, and I can see the Kafka metrics and work with Kafka shell command at the same time without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you've exported KAFKA_OPTS / KAFKA_JMX_OPTS environment variable, then it'll apply to every Kafka shell command, not only kafka-server-start. (Don't set both; KAFKA_OPTS is set to include KAFKA_JMX_OPTS)

You can use other tools like kcat to list topics, produce, and consume. Otherwise, you need different way to setup the JMX agent

Comment: @OneCricketeers I edited my question. Unfortunately I can't use kcat. Do you have any suggestion how can I setup JMX? Every sources that I found, just configured jmx by KAFKA_OPTS or KAFKA_JMX_OPTS.

Comment: You need to unset both `KAFKA_OPTS` and `KAFKA_JMX_OPTS` from the shell before you run any other commands. All kafka commands share the same base script, which is why you get the error in the same container... Why can't you run kcat in its own container? Or just install locally outside docker? Also, you should use `kafka-2_0_0.yml` file, assuming you're using latest Kafka versions

Answer (score -1):

Use a recent version of [jmx exporter](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.17.2/), and set the "KAFKA_OPTS" variable like that:

KAFKA_OPTS: "-javaagent:/opt/prometheus-jmx-exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar=7071:/opt/prometheus-jmx-exporter/kafka-2_0_0.yml"

Try to expose the port 7071:

```
ports:
  - 7071:7071
```

And use the same port in the scrape configs like :

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kafka-monitoring'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['yourhost:7071']
```

If the port 7071 doesn't work try another one

Comment: The error isn't coming from Docker Compose. It's a Java error.